# Breaking out of a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, try-catch, powershell-2.0

Currently using the following code to search a directory and copy any .msi that is found to another directory. I don't want to copy a .msi if it is in use by another program. I saw other questions on StackExchange that showed other ways to check if a file was in use but using a try/catch block around a `Rename-Item` command seemed like a simpler solution. If the script can't rename the item I want it go to the next `$file` in `$listoffiles`. The only way that I could get it to work was by using the code listed below. However I can't seem to format the resulting error message the way I want and it seems like `-ErrorAction Stop` shouldn't be necessary. If an error occurs in the `try` block shouldn't the error just go to the `catch` block? Also, only 2 of the 3 variables in my error message are written out to the log file.

Current code:

```
$listofFiles=(Get-ChildItem -Path $outputPath -Filter "*.msi" | where {$_.Name -notlike "*.Context.msi" -and $_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)})

foreach ($file in $listofFiles){
    $y = ($file -split ("\\"))
    $msiFolder = $y[4]

    #Tests to see if $file currently in use
    try{
        Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $file -ErrorVariable renameError -ErrorAction Stop 
    }
    catch{
        "$logTime ERROR Could not copy $msiFolder: $renameError.Exception.Message()" >> $copyLog
        continue
    }   

    #Code that copies files that are not in use.
```

Currently the error is displayed like so:

```
02/18/13 13:43:25 ERROR Could not copy  System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: Command execution stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.TryStatementNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context).Exception.Message()
```

I would like for it to look like:

```
02/18/13 13:34:34 ERROR Could not copy ABC_CLIENT: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

**Questions**

1. Why does $msiFolder not appear in the log message?
2. How do I get simplify the error message?
3. Is there a better way to use a try/catch block to break out of an iteration of the foreach loop?

**Update 1:**

I cleared `$error` and ran:

```
Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$?){"$logTime ERROR Could not copy $file: $error[0].Exception.Message()" >> $copyLog}
```

The result was:

```
02/18/13 14:52:59 ERROR Could not copy  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.[0].Exception.Message()
```

Why does `$logTime` get printed but the other variables do not?

**Update 2:**
Final code that I used:

```
Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
if (!$?){
    "$logTime ERROR Could not copy ${msiFolder}: $($error[0].Exception.Message)" >> $copyLog
    continue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use try/catch you need to convert the non-terminating error you get from Rename-Item to a terminating error.  That is why you need to use -ErrorAction Stop to make your catch block get invoked.  However, you can do this another way e.g.:

```
foreach ($file in $listofFiles){
    $y = ($file -split ("\\"))
    $msiFolder = $y[4]

    #Tests to see if $file currently in use
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $file -ErrorVariable renameError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$?) {
        "$logTime ERROR Could not copy ${msiFolder}: $($error[0].Exception.Message)" >> $copyLog
        continue
    }   

    #Code that copies files that are not in use.
}
```

The automatic variable `$?` indicates whether the last command succeeded or not.

As for why $msiFolder isn't getting output, I would check the split operation.  Check that $y.count is >= 5.

Comment: I like your solution but I needed to use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and using `$error[0].Exception.Message()` gives me the error message I'm looking for...along with everything else in `$error`. Even if I use `$file` instead of `$msiFolder` the variable is still not written out.

Comment: Good point on the silentlycontinue arg to -ErrorAction.  I updated the answer.  Ah try this "${msiFolder}:".  The colon after $msiFolder is messing you up.

Comment: `${msiFolder}` fixed getting the file name but I still can't get the error. I tried `${error[0].Exception.Message}` and `${$error[0].Exception.Message()}` but either didn't get the error message in the log or got everything in `$error`.

Comment: For the error message use `"blah $($error[0].Exception.Message) blah"`.